# how can I display a data table in flask app?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to display a data table in my flask app. 
Here is my example to simply display the `iris` dataset.

Below is my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def example():
    return render_template("example.html", value=iris)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is example.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>   
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>sepal_length</th>
          <th>sepal_width</th>
          <th>petal_length</th>
          <th>petal_width</th>
          <th>species</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for row in value %} 
          <tr>
            <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
            <td>{{row[4]}}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I got table like this:

```
sepal_length sepal_width petal_length petal_width   species
s   e   p   a   l
s   e   p   a   l
p   e   t   a   l
p   e   t   a   l
s   p   e   c   i
```

I spent hours trying to figure out what went wrong. I still have no idea why it does not work. Does anyone know why it happened?

Also, is there way in flask to display a nice-looking datatable, instead of coding in html? I'd be really surprised if there isn't.

Comment: If you need futher help in Flask please let me know and contact with  me on sharmagarg007@gmail.com mail.

Answer (score 1):

---

Actually you have put the template folder in wrong path that's why you got the TemplateNotFound error. You need to put the template folder in this location "os.path.abspath('templates')" and you have resolved this issue.

---

***app.py***

from flask import Flask, render_template

import seaborn as sns

import pandas as pd

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

template_dir = os.path.abspath('templates')

static_dir = os.path.abspath('static')

app = Flask(***__name__***, template_folder=template_dir, static_folder=static_dir,)

@app.route('/')

def example():

```
    return render_template("example.html", value=iris)
```

if ***__name__*** == ***'__main__'***:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Actually I realized that and put it in the templates folder. But I got weird looking table displayed.  I just edited question. sorry about that.

Comment: First you check that how 's data come in "value" variable., it is list or dictionary.
I think their is issue with "row[0]" in "vlaue".